# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis even after aplying duplicated()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, axis

I'm trying to do a time series forecasting using the following dataframe which contains two columns in a csv file ('input.csv'):

|  | Mean | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 0.9800 | 2020 |
| **1** | 1.0200 | 2020 |
| **2** | 0.9500 | 2019 |
| **3** | 0.9800 | 2019 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| **98** | -0.783 | 1971 |
| **99** | -0.0900 | 1971 |
| **100** | 0.0372 | 1970 |
| **101** | 0.0200 | 1970 |

1. First, I convert the column "Year" to DateTime using parse_dates:

   ```
    df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', parse_dates=['Year'])
   ```

After applying the code, the dataframe looks like this:

|  | Mean | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 0.9800 | 2020-01-01 |
| **1** | 1.0200 | 2020-01-01 |
| **2** | 0.9500 | 2019-01-01 |
| **3** | 0.9800 | 2019-01-01 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| **98** | -0.783 | 1971-01-01 |
| **99** | -0.0900 | 1971-01-01 |
| **100** | 0.0372 | 1970-01-01 |
| **101** | 0.0200 | 1970-01-01 |

2. Then I try to set up the time series into sets:

```
df = df.set_index('Year')
df = df.asfreq('MS')
df = df.sort_index()
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

3. Given that result, I've tried using duplicated() function before running code on point 2:

```
df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(), :]
```

Nevertheless, after applying duplicated() function I'm still having the same issue. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are running your operations in the wrong order. `asfreq` requires a non-duplicated, sorted index.

You should do:

```
df = df.set_index('Year')
df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated()].sort_index()
df = df.asfreq('MS')
```

output:

```
              Mean
Year              
1970-01-01  0.0372
1970-02-01     NaN
...
1970-12-01     NaN
1971-01-01 -0.7830
1971-02-01     NaN
...
2019-11-01     NaN
2019-12-01     NaN
2020-01-01  0.9800
```